# My object moves on the previous click position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object "Stick"(results[0].gameObject) and if I click on it with the right mouse button, then it moves on the previous click position. Why it happens?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9Xyzo0z_rE&feature=youtu.be

Code :

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Mouse1))
    {
        pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(eventSystem);
        pointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

        raycaster.Raycast(pointerEventData, results);
        if (results.Count != 0)
        {
            if (results[0].gameObject.tag == "ItemIcon")
            {
                RectTransform resultTransformParent;
                resultTransformParent = results[0].gameObject.transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
                if (currentMenu != null)
                    Destroy(currentMenu);
                currentMenu = Instantiate(SplitMenu, transform);
                Debug.Log(resultTransformParent.position);
                SplitMenu.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = new Vector3(resultTransformParent.anchoredPosition.x,381 - Math.Abs(resultTransformParent.anchoredPosition.y),0);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this "stick" object represented in the code you've shown?

Comment: results[0].gameObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, you are updating `SplitMenu`'s position instead of `currentMenu`.

`SplitMenu` is the prefab object, not the newly created object. So when you change its position the new object (`currentMenu`) doesn't move.

Next time you click, a new menu is created using the prefab - whose position was changed last time - so the new menu has position of last click.